# Firebase Update is Making New one With the same id except last character

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this code to update data on Firebase but it makes new one. I tried a lot of code and it dose the same making new one with same key except last character.

I used this as the Firebase site recommended, but it doesn't work. I created a new one and the next time its update:

```
    Map<String, Object> childUpdate = new HashMap<>();
childUpdate.put("/masjeds/" + masjed.getId(), masjed.toMap());
reference.updateChildren(childUpdate);
```

and this code done the same

```
     final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    masjeds = database.getReference("masjeds");

        reference.child(masjed.getId()).setValue(masjed, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
         //   Toast.makeText(MyMasjedsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Masjed Class is plain java object

```
public class Masjed {
private String userID;
private String id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;
private boolean matloopEmam;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public boolean isMatloopEmam() {
    return matloopEmam;
}

public void setMatloopEmam(boolean matloopEmam) {
    this.matloopEmam = matloopEmam;
}


public Masjed(String name, String address, String phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Masjed() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("address", address);
    map.put("phone", phone);
    map.put("id", id);
    map.put("userID", userID);
    return map;
}

}
```

[image]

the id is the problem I was assuming that push.getkey and put it as ID
then use push.setValue(masjed) will use the same key
it turn out that it is not always the Case the Key changes when I am use it dosnt exist and so it create new one the answer that helped me is Chester Answer

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).. We have no way of knowing what `masjed` is, nor what `reference` points to, nor what the data at that location looks like before and after calling `updateChildren`. Without these the help we can provide is likely a stab in the dark and at best an educated guess. With a MCVE we can likely do better.

Comment: Please add your database structure

Comment: it just a a list of class call Masjed Object Using push on masjeds Reference

Comment: How are you setting masjed.id? Is it a "push ID" that Firebase figured out for you (ie, something like "-KgCONuXLRSgJFKLzg6i")? Or are is it something else? From the way you set up the childUpdate parameters, it looks like it must be a "push ID". But that seems odd, since normally you'd have a database structure where "masjeds" has a bunch of child nodes like "-KgCONuXLRSgJFKLzg6i", and then each of these child nodes has properties like "name", "address", "phone" (but not the same ID again). Please explain what "masjed.id" is and some more about your database structure, so we can help you.

Comment: Please add firebase data structure or screenshot of that.

Comment: i added the database structure screen shot

Comment: In your screenshot, I have see it look like `same id` but I don't see **except last character**, please point it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps, used it in my pet project (it's not the cleans solution but it works):

```
masjeds = database.getReference("masjeds");

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
                masjedKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey(); // This is a member variable
                masjed = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Masjed.class); // This is a member variable
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
masjeds.orderByChild("id").equalTo(masjed.getId()).addValueEventListener(listener);

//Use your Map to update each value this is just an example
masjeds.child(masjedKey).child("name").setValue("John"); //you can add event listener if you want to see if it's completed, but it works without the events
```

Comment: still creating new node with the same key except last char

Comment: As @Rapunzel Van Winkle suggested could you provide your database structure?

Comment: As @Phan Van Linh pointed out the id field is the same for each JSON object in the screenshot, I would assume your problem is the id is not being set correctly.

Comment: the id is the problem I was assuming that push.getkey and put it as ID then use push.setValue(masjed) will use the same key it turn out that it is not always the Case the Key changes when I am use it dosnt exist and so it create new one the answer that helped me is Chester Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   masjeds = database.getReference("masjeds");

    // ** what is reference here? This must be masjeds **
    reference.child(masjed.getId()).setValue(masjed, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
     //   Toast.makeText(MyMasjedsActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I have added my findings as a comment above which I found as a suspect, you might be pointing to wrong reference. You are targeting to `reference` node while `masjeds` node is unused. Please verify it and for better understanding put Database of firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, to update the children of a specific node with the contents of your HashMap:

```
// get a reference to the node that you want to update
DatabaseReference masjedToUpdate = masjeds.child(masjed.getId());
// pass your hashmap to its "updateChildren" method
masjedToUpdate.updateChildren(masjed.toMap());
```

Note that this approach is still a little nonstandard, for a couple of reasons. But it should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update FireBase by use

```
mDatabase.child("masjed").child("the_key_of_child_you_want_to_update").setValue(masjedObject);
```

will work normally, it will not create new child

You can check [My demo here](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/StackOverFlowDemo/tree/master/FireBaseUpdateDemo)