# How to Update Items in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the data I want to update:

```
"users": [
    "-KTYWvZG4Qn9ZYTc47O6": {
        "name": "name"
        "email": "email"
    }
]
```

My code:

```
private void update1(String s, String name,String email) {

    String key = mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();

    user1 user = new users1(name, email);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = user.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/users/" + key, postValues);

    mFirebaseDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Why does it create a new node?

```
"users": [
    "-KTYWvZG4Qn9ZYTc47O6" : {
        "name" : "name"
        "email" : "email"
   }
]
"users": [
    "-KeZvOQ8HYrNXvuPBe8z" : {
        "name" : "name2"
        "email" : "email2"
    }
]
```

Comment: `mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();` creates a new node (with a new key) - what else did you think this does?

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559444/firebase-update-is-making-new-one-with-the-same-id-except-last-character/43034019#43034019

Comment: What are you trying to do, add a new user in `users` or updating existing one?

Comment: updating existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the nodes by unique value like email in your example
using this code 
youReference= database.getReference("masjeds");

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
                masjedKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey(); // This is a member variable
                masjed = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Masjed.class); // This is a member variable
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
masjeds.orderByChild("id").equalTo(masjed.getId()).addValueEventListener(listener);
```

then get key using

```
datasnapshot.getkey ()
```

update it using

```
youReference.child(masjedKey).child("name").setValue("John")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new node by using [`push`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) ("create a reference to an auto-generated child location") method in:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();
```

Just remove it and this will update existing `users` node:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child("users").getKey();
```

Comment: same problem                                             !!